# Python: A histogram for selected columns split by a variable

Tags: python, data-visualization

I do most of my work in R and am trying to explore a bit more of Python. My fluency of the latter is pretty rubbish so explaining anything super simple won't offend me :)

I am starting some exploratory analysis and want to show the distribution of each variable by what will become the target variable. The outcome I would like a histogram for every column in the DF with the data split by the target.  Writing in R this is super simple, in the example below x,z and y are the columns and 'cut' the target.

How could I reproduce this in Python?

```
# R
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

shinyStuff <- gather(diamonds,KPI,numbers,x:z)

ggplot(data = shinyStuff)+geom_histogram(aes(x=numbers,color=cut),stat='count') + facet_wrap(~KPI)
```

[image]

I have tried looping over DF like this:

```
# Python
for num, col in enumerate(diamonds):
    print(num)
    plt.figure()
    axs[num].hist(diamonds[diamonds['cut']=='Fair'].iloc[:,num],alpha=0.6)
    axs[num].hist(diamonds[diamonds['cut']=='Good'].iloc[:,num],alpha=0.6)
```

This didn't work full stop.

I have tried splitting the DF and mapping

```
# Python
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
diamonds[diamonds['Cut']=='Fair'].hist(figsize = (16,20),color='red',ax=ax,alpha=0.6)
diamonds[diamonds['Cut']=='Good'].hist(figsize = (16,20),color='blue',ax=ax,alpha=0.6);
```

This just over writes the first.

Tried a few more things which I won't post - they may well have been along the write lines but I am not versed enough in Python to get them right so I don't think a list of failed examples will help here.

I am using Python 3 and open to all solutions using any dependencies.